# Word that means "to physically enter, as a parasite"

Tags: single-word-requests

Some creatures have tendrils, which they will parasitically insert into another living creature. I'm looking for the work that would complete this sentence:

"The parasitic bug ____ its tendrils into the elephant"

(N.B. I am not a biologist; my apologies if this kind of situation does not arise in nature)

Words that I have used instead, but don't quite seem to be right:

- Extended
- Embedded
- Inserted

All of these imply some kind of penetration, but none have the inflection of parasitism.

Is there a word for what I am looking for?

Thanks

Comment: Another potentially word is **infiltrate**.

Comment: Creatures don't have tendrils. Plants have tendrils.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb [**to invade**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invade) seems to be the word you're looking for:

> **1.2** (of a parasite or disease) spread into (an organism or bodily part)
>
> ‘sometimes the worms invade the central nervous system’

The verb [**to irrupt**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrupt) is also a good choice:

> **2** *of a natural population*: to undergo a sudden upsurge in numbers especially when natural ecological balances and checks are
>   disturbed

(A *natural population* applies, I think, to parasites, as well).

And [**to infest**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/infest) seems to be another good choice, and also more technical than the other two:

> **2** (of parasites such as lice) *to invade* and live on or in (a host)

Comment: Invade works perfectly. Also, irrupt seems to be a handy word worth knowing about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try **Injected**

1. introduce (something) under pressure into a passage, cavity, or solid material.

*The parasitic bug **injected** its tendrils into the elephant*

Another option is **Pierce**

*The parasitic bug's tendrils **pierced** into the elephant*

Comment: Your usage of pierce is incorrect. It should say "The parasitic bug's tendrils pierced the elephant['s skin]".

Comment: Yes you are correct .. will edit my answer